# How to prevent single click trigger when double clicked without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, mouseevent, dom-events

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow, but I haven't found the proper solution.

In the case of double click, I don't want a single click function to be triggered, and I would like to archive this without jQuery and setTimeout.

This can be achieved with setTimeout, but then mouse move event is blocked for the delay time.

Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnrk3xk115

```
mouseDown = (e) => {
    // Case 1
    // In the case of double clicks, a single click will still trigger. 
    if (e.detail === 1) {
      console.log('Single Click');
    } else if (e.detail === 2) {
      console.log('Double Click');
    }

    // Case 2
    // In the case, I can't use mouse move for 250ms
    let timeoutID = null;

    if (!timeoutID) {
      timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Single Click');
        timeoutID = null;
      }, 250);
    } else {
      timeoutID = clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      console.log('Double Click');
    }
  }

  mouseMove = () => {
    // Mouse move is blocked for 250ms
  }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you'd effectively have to see into the future. Maybe reduce the timeout to make it less of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think setTimeout is necessary, but you can use it in a different way.
Flag your function for a click, and then use the timeout to reset it to avoid the double click.

Please take a look at the below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/73n357xx36

If I get the idea right, it should suit your needs.